# Can I create a custom form elements(upload, dropdown, checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

Is it possible for me to add a customised upload button, like in below screenshot..

When Clicked on upload and you choose a image, a dropdown appears,

How is it done? I would like add a couple of fields and some check box like in the site
for demo http:/foodspotting.com

Is there a Jquery plugin available for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uploadify Jquery plugin ...

http://www.uploadify.com/

Here u will need to use onSelect option

"The onSelect option allows you to run a custom function for each file when being added to the queue.  The default function creates a new queue item for the file and places it in the queue.  If the custom function returns false, the default function will not run."

[More details](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onselect/)

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 3):

Why need a jQuery plugin? Showing a div with additional controls can be done in a single line of Javascript.

Basically you don't need more than a form, hide part of it using css, and show it after the button is clicked using a tiny piece of Javascript.

Of course you can use JQuery to animate it, but that's all just fancy stuff. No specific plugins needed.

Answer (score 3):

See the following:

Plupload: a plugin using jQuery.

> http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php

Using this, you can customize & trigger another function which can open-up an dialog-box and you can fill-up your stuff.